# How can I use less than sign "<" in a string in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

In a camel configuration file, I define a password that contains a less-than-sign "<". Then it will fail when I startup JBoss. The escape char backslash doesn't work in this situation. How can I include this sign in a string?

```
<configuration xsi:type="ProviderConfiguration" ...........>
    <provider controlName="Whisky">
        <entry xsi:type=Simple" name="password" value="abcabc<ABC">
    </provider>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What’s the failure?

Comment: what about using `RAW()` ? https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Configuringparametervaluesusingrawvalues

Comment: It has nothing to see with Camel but with XML. The `<` char has to be escaped as `&lt;` (for lower than)

Comment: @TacheDeChoco Appreciated your answer. Yes, you spot the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TacheDeChoco. This doesn't relate to Camel but XML. replace "<" with `&lt;` and it works.